# Can't call another method from LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have a c# statement which iterate thru a collection of row. One of the fields call a private method to get an array of object but I am getting null. I placed a breakpoint inside the linq but it never hits the method.

Here is my code

```
IQueryable<MyObject> myObject = ds.Tables['Table'].AsEnumerable().Select(row => new MyObject
{
  id = row.Field<int>("ID"),
  MyCollectionArray = this.getCollectionArray(row.Field<string>("MyAggregatedString")),
}).AsQueryable();

private MyObect[] getCollectionArray(string concatString)
{

  // placed a breakpoint, it is never called. Not sure why
}
```

Thanks for any asistance.

Comment: You need to materialise the sequence, for example by adding a `.ToList()` to the end of your query. Just declaring a Linq sequence doesn't actually enumerate its content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are facing is called [Deferred Execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/deferred-execution-and-lazy-evaluation-in-linq-to-xml).
Which means that your query is not executed until you use it somewhere.
Here is a part from the documentation:

> Deferred execution means that the evaluation of an expression is
>   delayed until its realized value is actually required. Deferred
>   execution can greatly improve performance when you have to manipulate
>   large data collections, especially in programs that contain a series
>   of chained queries or manipulations. In the best case, deferred
>   execution enables only a single iteration through the source
>   collection.

And in order to execute your statement you just have to use it.
The simplest way might be just by calling

```
myObject.ToList()
```

Also it will be executed in case you use functions which require the values to be populated (like Sum, Average, etc)